# iOS: Sharing state/properties between 3 controllers

Tags: ios

I have a form and it gives users an advance mode. I've already googled and looked around at different SO questions (sharing data between controllers, protocols, and passing data between segues) but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

**Is there a way for me to have some sort of "master controller" that holds all the data while going back and forth between 3 different controllers?**

If I can just hold the data for the second controller and allow my user to make that quick advance edit in the third while keeping it's data intact, that'll do for now.

Thanks in advance

---

Here's a quick walkthrough of my app:

1. FirstViewController: User selects an option
2. SecondViewController: User does some editing while storing that option
3. (*Optional)ThirdViewControl: User one more quick edit using a web view

*xcode5/iOS7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are passing data from one view controller to the next and you are using segues, then call a method on the next view controller in line from `prepareForSegue`. For example, when segueing between ViewController1 and ViewController2, add this code to ViewController1 and repeat as necessary in other view controllers:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    ViewController2 *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;

    [viewController configureWithSomeState:self.someState];
}
```

This code assumes that `someState` is a property defined on `ViewController1`.

EDIT: One thing you *could* do--although I do not like this approach because it forces your VCs to have special knowledge about their parent controller--is to derive UINavigationController, then in your storyboard, use the new class for your navigation controller. Store the state in the derived navigation controller and access it from each VC like this:

```
DerivedNavigationController *navigationController = (DerivedNavigationController *)self.navigationController;

navigationController.someState...;
```

Comment: Yep, I'm doing this now (second sentence in question), I'm just looking for a better way now that I've added a 3rd controller

Comment: In the second controller, do the same thing. There really aren't any other choices because each VC is a separate instance in memory; you can either pass state from one VC to the next or use a singleton object to store state global to the application. Is there some particular aversion you have to this approach?

Comment: Yep, this seems to be the case. Thanks :/

Answer (score 0):

Typically I'd put information that is used throughout the application in the application delegate where everybody has access to it.

Another possibility is to implement a singleton data management class to hold it for you.

In this case it seems like the application is really a pretty linear flow, so I'd just pass the selection from vc1 to vc2 and then again to vc3 in the respective prepareForSegue calls.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the reply. It's not used throughout the application, it's more of a form. I'm researching singleton data management classes like you suggested. The only thing I'm worried about is memory and performance. vc2 is actually the final view before posting -- so users that go to vc3 will always return to vc2 and may even edit some stuff on vc1

Comment: Just looked into singletons. The carry data around throughout the entire lifecycle of the app? I only would like to pass data around between 3 controllers (sort of like a multi-step form..)

Comment: Yeah, that's where the third model comes in, just pass it from controller to controller using prepareForSegue and the delegate model.  Nathan gives details on the prepareForSegue part of ot.  To get info from the third back to the second use a delegate (or completion block) that you set up there.